Android : ParkSquare.Discogs nuget crashes on search on Android but not on Windows
ParkSquare.Discogs nuget crashes on search on Android but not on Windows.
Simple code:
string ArtistName = "AnyArtistName"; //Just any artist name
string AlbumName = "AnyAlbumName";   //Just any album name
int Year = 1999;                     //Just any year

SearchCriteria SearchCriteriaWithYear = new()
{
    Artist = ArtistName ,
    Title = AlbumName ,
    Year = Year ,
    Type = "album"
};
SearchResults ArtistSearchResult = await client.SearchAsync(SearchCriteriaWithYear);

Running this code app crashes and give following exception:
"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')"
This same code works well on windows side. Any idea what might causes this problem?
Edit:
Stack Trace show following:
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.RuntimeNativeMethods.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception   C#

0x1A in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#

0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23,26    C#

0x17 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#

0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0 C#

0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#

0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:37,6 C#

0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#

0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#


What does the stack trace show?  Have you searched the bug repo for that package?
